# Correct way to set up users and permissions for server side scripts that write to files?

Tags: linux, php, permissions

I have an program that runs on my server (AWS EC2), which does some computing and produces some log files.  The program is C++ but is launched from a PHP script via web.

What is the "correct" way to set up the users and permissions for this to work?  For example, should I create a user just for running the process, and output the log files to that user's home folder?

Or should there be an "output" folder with public write permissions?

A nudge in the right direction would be helpful...

Answer (score 0):

Following the [*principle of least privilege*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege):

- your PHP page need the privilege to run your binary
- your binary need some privilege to do their work

But all depends on how your PHP call the binary, part that you haven't described.